# Masking the input to model as a graph

Tags: huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I was wondering if it is possible to mask the input in order to get attention like in GNNs. Specifically, if there was a way to send an attention mask in 2D we could tell a token to attend just to its neighbours and not the other tokens. Is this behaviour possible for example using a pretrained language model from Huggingface?